# Calling function in Swift Class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
        ParseHelper.timelineRequestForCurrentUser{
        (result: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.posts = result as? [Post] ?? []

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

When I try running this method I get,  "use of unresolved identifier"

This is my class:

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class ParseHelper {

// 2
static func timelineRequestForCurrentUser(completionBlock: PFQueryArrayResultBlock) {
    let followingQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follow")
    followingQuery.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)

    let postsFromFollowedUsers = Post.query()
    postsFromFollowedUsers!.whereKey("user", matchesKey: "toUser", inQuery: followingQuery)

    let postsFromThisUser = Post.query()
    postsFromThisUser!.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([postsFromFollowedUsers!, postsFromThisUser!])
    query.includeKey("user")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    // 3
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completionBlock)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen and what could be a good solution for it?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Use of unresolved identifier ....? It'll give you a name.

Comment: Side note - why are you building a new app with Parse? They will be discontinued in a few months.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 right where I call the method .timelinerequestforcurrentuser()

Comment: @aaron bragar I know that but for now it's a proof of concept for myself. I'm a bit new to the world of iOS development and wanted to get a solid start with something I was familiar with

Comment: Have you written this class in another file and using it in another file?

Comment: Yes i wrote it in a seperate file. Trying to now call that function from the file into this this function. I see the ParseHelper class and the function Xcode but when I type t put but when I try and resolve and compile the error just keeps coming. Back.

Comment: You've to make that class public. Then you can use it how you are using now. Make the function public as well. Then call it with className.functionName

Comment: Tried that already .. did not work.. @Dershowitz123

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding the class right into the file. though from experience I know I should not have to do it. If anyone comes up with an answer let me know. But the best method right now is just put the class right into the file.